# How can I get rid of "Trojan:Win32/Manrele.G!cl"?

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware, windows-defender, avg-antivirus

Windows Defender pops up every 30 seconds or so and says it has removed malware called "Trojan:Win32/Manrele.G!cl". Obviously it's missing something, or this wouldn't keep happening.

I'm running Windows 10, and both Windows and Windows Defender are fully up to date (I ran updates on both yesterday).

I've run a Quick and a Full scan with Windows Defender, as well as a Full and a Deep scan with AVG. Neither said they actually caught anything.

[Supposedly Windows Defender can resolve this issue](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Trojan:Win32/Manrele.G!cl), but it has definitely failed to do so. Or at least, it has failed to stop it from re-occurring.

I'm at a loss as to what to do at this point. I could reformat, but I have 3 hard drives, and I don't want to go through the trouble of reformatting my windows drive if the issue lives on in one of the two other drives (one of which is my data backup drive, and I really don't want to reformat that).

Any suggestions as how I can resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you start it, any copy of the malware on secondary drives is harmless. Random programs don’t start themselves, after all. That being said – nuke it.

Answer (score 1):

> I could reformat, but I have 3 hard drives, and I don't want to go through
>   the trouble of reformatting my windows drive if the issue lives on in one
>   of the two other drives

Disconnecting a drive is easy. Either physically or simply not mounting it. The latter can be done from `diskmgmt.msc` (run it,select the volume you want to change. Click on "change drive letters and paths" to change/remove either the drive letter or the path it is mounted on.

That way you can at least pin it down to which disk the problem is on. If it is the OS disk then please read [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit/157533#157533).

If it is on a data disk then you should be able to just deleted or quarantine the suspected file. So I suspect it is on the OS disk.

> both Windows and Windows Defender are fully up to date (I ran updates on
>   both yesterday).

If the infection occurred before you updated then there is no guarantee that you have a reliable system.

Regardless, try unmounting the non OS volumes. You may be lucky.

Failing that, run a malware scan again while booted from something else than your main disk. (live live CD, windows live CD, live CD on USB, HDD moved to a different computers.... lots of options here).

---

Not part of your question but I had to react to this:

> one of which is my data backup drive

I hope you also have another backup. A backup drive in the computer is nice, but if lightning strikes, the home burns down, the PC is stolen or similar than you would loose both live data and the backup.